# ProgressDialog некорректно работает

Tags: android, java, многопоточность

Столкнулся с довольно непонятной проблемой при тестировании работы ProgressDialog. Замысел примера в том, что в отдельном потоке увеличивается значение диалога прогресса. Когда при нажатии на кнопку вызывается ProgressDialog, после его завершения появляется Toast, который не смотря на короткое время показа не исчезает вовсе. Повторный запуск диалога приводит к почти мгновенному его выполнению и завершению . Более того, при выходе из приложения возникает ошибка "Произошла неожиданная остановка приложения... Повторите попытку." Как разрешить ситуацию?

Код перегруженного **Thread**'a

```
package com.samples.progressdialog;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;

public class SecondThread extends Thread{
Handler mHandler;
final static int STATE_DONE = 0;
final static int STATE_RUNNING = 0;
int mState;
int mTotal;

SecondThread (Handler hnd) {
    mHandler = hnd;
}
public void run() {
    mState = STATE_RUNNING;
    mTotal = 0;
    while (mState == STATE_RUNNING) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            Log.e("ERROR", "THREAD INTERRUPTED");
        }
        Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putInt("Total", mTotal);
        msg.setData(b);
        mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
        mTotal++;
    }
}
public void setState (int state) {
    mState = state;
}
}
```

**Код основного файла**

```
package com.samples.progressdialog;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ProgressDialogActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
static final int IDD_PROGRESS = 0;

private SecondThread mSecondThread;
private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final Button callButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    callButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            showDialog(IDD_PROGRESS);
        }
    });
}
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch(id) {
    case IDD_PROGRESS :
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(ProgressDialogActivity.this);
        mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Идёт загрузка чего-то там ... Пожалуйста ждите ");
        mSecondThread = new SecondThread(handler);
        mSecondThread.start();
        return mProgressDialog;
    default:
        return null;
    }
}
final Handler handler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg){
        int total = msg.getData().getInt("Total");
        mProgressDialog.setProgress(total);
        if (total >=100) {
            dismissDialog(IDD_PROGRESS);
            mSecondThread.setState(SecondThread.STATE_DONE);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Task is finished", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

};
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Реализовал задачу с использованием рекомендованного AsyncTask.

Перегруженный AsyncTask - **ProgressTask.java**

```
package com.apps.myapptest.core;

import android.os.AsyncTask;

public class ProgressTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Boolean>{
private IProgressTracker mProgressTracker;
private Integer Progress = 0;

public ProgressTask (IProgressTracker progressTracker) {
    mProgressTracker = progressTracker;
}

@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
    while (Progress <100) {
        if (isCancelled()) {
            return false;
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
            publishProgress(Progress);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    Progress++;
    }
    return true;
}
@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
    mProgressTracker.onProgress(progress[0]);
}
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
    if (result) mProgressTracker.onComplete();
    else mProgressTracker.onCancel();
}
}
```

Файл главной деятельности **MyAppTestActivity.java**

```
package com.apps.myapptest;

import com.apps.myapptest.core.ProgressTask;
import com.apps.myapptest.core.IProgressTracker;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MyAppTestActivity extends Activity implements IProgressTracker{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    private ProgressTask mAsyncTask;
    static final int IDD_PROGRESS = 0;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Button callButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonProgress);
        callButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                showDialog(IDD_PROGRESS);
            }
        });
    }
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch(id) {
        case IDD_PROGRESS: 
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            mProgressDialog.setCancelable(true);
            //mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Ждите... Идёт загрузка");
            mAsyncTask = new ProgressTask(this);
            mAsyncTask.execute();
            return mProgressDialog;
        default:
            return null;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onProgress(Integer progress) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (!mProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
            mProgressDialog.show();
        }
        if (progress <= 100) {
            mProgressDialog.setProgress(progress);
        }
        else {
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Task is finished", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Task is cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
    }
```

Интерфейс **IProgressTracker.java**

```
package com.apps.myapptest.core;

public interface IProgressTracker {
    void onProgress(Integer progress);
    void onComplete();
    void onCancel();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Проблема с повторным вызовом диалога заключается в кешировании диалогов, при вызове `showDialog()`, `onCreateDialog()` вызывается только один раз, при первом вызове. Впоследствии диалог не разрушается, а просто достаётся из "кеша", но при этом вызывается `onPrepareDialog()`. Т.к. поток запускается в `onCreateDialog()`, то при повторном вызове он просто не стартует.

Можно попробовать запускать поток в `onPrepareDialog()`, но я рекомендовал бы с thread'ов перейти на [AsynTask](http://d.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), там это сделать проще.